# Do we answer questions that may have malicious intent?

Tags: discussion, ethics, malicious-code

What do we do if we come across a question that *could* have malicious intent behind it. I found [one such question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605773/1607646#1607646) and don't know what the normal practice regarding these questions is.

Do we flag them? Not answer them? Not worry about them?

#### Related

> [Would you teach BlackHat techniques in public forums?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12621/would-you-teach-black-hat-techniques-in-public-forums)

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/questions-with-nefarious-intent

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12621/would-you-teach-black-hat-techniques-in-public-forums

Answer (score 2):

That question must have a good, safe, helpful use. Anybody with malicious intent can get that information on more suitable boards, but SO won't ever become a comprehensive resource if we don't allow potentially harmful questions.

Plus, if you know how something bad is done, you're one step closer to combating it. It's good stuff to know.

edit: Alright, reading the question it seems he wants it for an "unkillable process"
That seems very fishy, but I still believe that it's good information to know, and he could get it somewhere else if he had truly malicious intent.

Comment: Yeah - you can see the reason for my concern. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

If you feel that a question is asking for help on activities that would be illegal or immoral flag it for a moderator to deal with immediately.